# facebook-twitter like login system in php

Tags: php

I have 2 websites with a member login system.

Members are registered at one website.

I want that all members registered at website "A", should not need to register at websites "B".
By using the credentials at website "A", members should be able to login at website "B".

It also should be in a secure way.

Comment: What should i do to accept answers to other questions ?

Comment: There is a transparent "[yes check](http://icongal.com/gallery/image/89444/confirmed_yes_check_ok_accept_positiv_green.png)" below the score of each answer. Simply click on the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok, i got it. thank now i will mark all checked answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all your authentication on website A, and use encryption to sign in to site B. So, if a user signs into site A, they are redirected to the first site, successfully authenticated, and then redirected with a hash to site B.

The hash can be something like this:

`sha1( shared_secret + username + time_rounded_to_2_mins )`

This can be easily checked on site B, and since it contains an approximation of the time, is not susceptible to replay attacks. I've done something similar, and it works very well. (The time approximation allows for a small variation in server clocks - but if they are out by more than your approximation level, it won't work.)

Comment: I want all things to work like below.
If member is already login to website A, then it should be automatic login into website B.
AND if the member log out of any of website then it should be logged out to both of websites.

Is it possible to share same session between them or something like that ?

Comment: No. Sessions are based on cookies which work per-domain (that is, a session on mywebsite.com will never work on myotherwebsite.com). Do you control anything at all on website A? If not, it would be a security hole to allow shared credentials or sessions.

Comment: @RAJESHBANSAL: yes, you can do that. When site B redirects to the login page of site A, you detect that and send the authenticated redirect immediately. When you do a log-out on either site, you could redirect to the other, sending a different authenticated token to log them out, and then redirect back again.

Comment: (Added new comment about the time approximation)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to have both website share the same database. Simply use the same table for users in both websites: users registered at website A or B will be able to login at website A or B.

Does website B have access to the database of website A?

Comment: Website A does not have access to website B. Website A does not share dababase credentials with website B.
I want that for when member want to login, it should be redirected to website A login form and after successfully login, it should be redirected to website B as authorize user and it should be able to access the member's area.