# Secure cross-domain authentication form

Tags: php, security, cross-domain, forms-authentication

I have a server 'A'. You have a server 'B'. Server 'A' wants to provide a login form to server 'B' (username and password).

How can I implement that scenario where server 'B' can't see/intercept those content filled by an user? The credentials must arrive in a secure way on server 'A' without interception.

Is that possible?

Here's a better example:

Server **A** offer a service to server **B** and server **B** offer a service to an **user** that has a password into server **A**. At some point, the **user** have to authenticate in server **A** but the login form will be displayed into a server's **B** page. Am I clear? And server **B** can't read those credentials.

The business logic is Server **A** has many clients and server **A** will allow third parties to develop applications to server's **A** clients. Who owns the master password is server **A** and server **B** can't access/read/intercept those credentials. The way clients will be authenticated on server **B** is by a login form embedded in server **B** (I can't redirect user to server **A**. The user has to stay on server's **B** page.).

The questions are:

What is the better way to embed the form in server **B**?

Can server **B** run JavaScript that will able to read the user's credentials before the submit?

Comment: I don't have a `server`, it's just server (you) and client (us). And the only 100% way to protect middle in the man attacks are ssl/https.

Comment: I think he is saying that he wants to be able to put a login form on server B that posts to server A, but not allow access to the posted data on server B. Like a way for someone to login to site B with credentials from site A. Sounds like an implementation of openid or something like the google/facebook login.

Comment: You can do this without SSL by posting from Server A to self, then encrypting using a shared secret, then using cURL to contact Server B. However, the path from the user to Server A is still technically prone to interception. Can you offer a bit more context as to what you are trying to protect against?

Comment: Is [this perhaps a dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9257865/472495)?

Comment: Also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9843982/472495). @Tulio, can you add more detail?

Comment: @halfer Server 'A' offer a service to server 'B' and server 'B' offer a service to user that has a password into server 'A'. At some point, the user have to authenticate in server 'A' but the login form will be displayed into a server's 'B' page. Am I clear? And server 'B' can't read those credentials.

Comment: If 'B' is considered a security risk, but is responsible for serving an `iframe` in such a way that it cannot read security details belongs to server 'A', then it sounds like the premise is flawed. What if 'B' decides to swap its `iframe` for a form? - users would then supply their credentials to a site you don't think is trustworthy. As for a solution, well the problem is still rather abstract. Why not _edit the question_ with what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Still rather abstract, imo. Who owns B (what business relationship do you have with them)? Is this a service that can be embedded with third parties? Why would you want to display a login form for site A on site B? Is this to permit site B to do something on A's behalf? If so, perhaps you need SSO (single-sign on) like Jonathan suggested, with limited permissions in light of B's limited trustworthiness.

Comment: Perhaps A should implement secondary passwords, or API keys. Or perhaps you should click on something in B, it redirects to A, gets user permission from your site, and redirects back to B with an authentication token. That has the benefit that you're not encouraging the user to enter their main password in a site they should not absolutely trust.

Comment: @halfer I wrote the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds like you are trying to pass sensitive data through Server B, but B is not the final destination.  Even if B is the destination (or the source), the answer is still the same

The way to do this is with HTTPS/TLS/SSL.  This will encrypt the data using A's public certificate, such that the data can only be decrypted by A's private key, which only A has.

This also provides the added benefit of verifying A's identity to the client.  A provides a certificate which is signed with A's private key.  Only A's public key will decrypt it properly, thus proving that only A could have generated that certificate (or someone stole it, but we assume this isn't the case).

EDIT:

To do this by having B serve the page but not be able to read it's data, have the web page served by B encrypt the data using Javascript on the client side, with A's public key (which can be included in the page by B).  Even though B has A's public key, it will not be able to decrypt the data encrypted by the JS.  It can only pass it on to A.

EDIT:

As long as all encryption is done on the client side using A's public key, the data will be unreadable by any parties other than A, because only A's private key will be able to decrypt it.  With this method you can have as many intermediaries as you want without risk.*

*This of course assumes an RSA key pair with sufficient entropy and length as to be considered secure.  A minimum of 1024-bit, preferably 2048-bit.

**Yet Another (and final) EDIT: 09-May-2013**

Sorry about the many edits, but your question has been confusing for me.  I think I understand now what you are asking.

In my previous posts I made a significant assumption, and that is that Server B is trusted not to make a malicious attempt to harvest your user's credentials.  I made this assumption because, as halfer alluded to in the comments, it is very unwise and unsafe to allow B to collect your user's credentials, if B is of limited trustworthiness in the first place.  Additionally, I made this assumption because it is a common task to use third parties to host your web app, such as Heroku, Amazon, etc., who would not be malicious (they would lose a ton of business if they did, and they have little to nothing to gain.  Also, you have someone to hold accountable if you detect security violations.  Thus they can be trusted, or you wouldn't be using them in the first place).  I will now assume that you are *not* using a third party source like them, since it seems apparent that that is the case.

If B could potentially be malicious, then no matter what you do with your client side code, B could change it and intercept the credentials.  As long as B could be trusted not to modify your client side code, then my previous suggestion would work.  However, given this new information that B is of limited trustworthiness, it would be unwise to implement my previous suggestion.

Authenticating a user to your service through an untrusted third party is a very dangerous endeavor, as indicated by the amount of money that PayPal has spent building an API.  However, if you must do this, then you will need to be very careful, and consider implementing [a solution similar to PayPal](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_shoppingcartresources.html).

If you have to go through the third party, then a solution similar to what @halfer mentioned in the comment above is the way to go, IMO.

> [P]erhaps you should click on something in B, it redirects to A, gets
>   user permission from your site, and redirects back to B with an
>   authentication token. That has the benefit that you're not encouraging
>   the user to enter their main password in a site they should not
>   absolutely trust.

Have the user redirected to your site *using HTTPS/TLS/SSL*.  This protects the user's credentials and also verifies your identity to the user so they're less likely to fall for a pharming attack.  You can then provide a sufficiently random token to the third party to use as authentication.

Please understand however, that even with this solution there is still significant risk.  If B wants to attack your users, B could still easily trick a percentage of them by simply asking them for their login credentials directly.  This would probably work against the majority of them, who aren't security savvy.

If B is not trusted, then my professional advice is *don't do this*.

Comment: But I will embed a form within iframe or something like that into server 'B', is there a way that server 'B' can read the data filled by an user? Those data are sensitive!

Comment: If B does not have A's private key, then no B, cannot read the data (that's encrypted with A's public key).  Make sure your JS routine won't submit data in the clear though if the encryption routine fails for some reason.  I don't know of existing libraries for this, so you may have to code it yourself.  Shouldn't be hard though.

Comment: Let's say I use [jcryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) to encrypt my form data before send. Can server 'B' create a javascript that will capture the form data? The best way to embed the form is with iframes?

Comment: jcryption looks cool.  With jcryption if you encrypt your form data with A's RSA Public key (instead of negotiating an AES key which B could sniff), and then decrypt the submission on A by decrypting with A's RSA Private key, then you will be good.  Using this method, iframes would be fine either way.

Comment: @Freedom: good post. It looks like the OP could do with setting up secret keys, like one does for Twitter third party systems (e.g. Wordpress plugins that are authorised to auto-tweet). As you say, if user authentication is required, server B could offer a form to redirect to A, A signs the request and redirects back again, after getting permission and/or credentials as required. +1

Comment: (Btw, on StackOverflow, you generally don't need to do `Edit:Edit:Edit` tagging, since we're trying to build canonical answers. If part of your answer was wrong in light of an update, be willing to throw it away, and rewrite it as you would have done for the updated question.)